Terraform Create eks_managed_node_groups based on a list
in terraform i want to create managed node groups based on a variable's array/list, my variables is like:
{
    "region" : "us-east-1",
    "clusters": [
        {
            "name": "simething",
            "database": {
                "instance_type": "db.t3.micro"
            },
            "eks_workers": [
                {
                    "name": "nodes1",
                    "instance_type": ["t3.micro"],
                },
                {
                    "name": "nodes2",
                    "instance_type": ["t3.micro"],
                }
            ]   
        }
    ]
}

and my variables definition:

variable "clusters" {
  description = "List of cluster configurations"
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    fqdn = string
    sip_fqdn = string
    database = object({
      instance_type = string
    })
    eks_workers = list(
      object({
        name = string
        instance_type = list(string)
      })
    )
  }))
}

I would like to use it like:
module "eks" {
  source                                = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  ...

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
      for worker in var.clusters[*].eks_workers: worker.name => {
        instance_type                 = worker.instance_type


or even
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    for cluster in var.clusters : 
    for worker_group_key, worker_group in cluster.eks_workers : 
    "${cluster.name}-${worker_group_key}" => {

so that I end up with a proper group block like:
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
      "nodes1" => {
        instance_type                 = ["t3.micro"]
        ...
      }
      "nodes2" => {
        instance_type                 = ["t3.micro"]
        ...
      }


but no matter what i do i don't seem to be able to use a for nested in a for...
Can anyone help?
Thanks

The clusters value has more than one cluster, right?

Yep,!thats what I want. I want to be able to configure the number of workgroups and clusters dynamically

With a little bit of shuffling things around, this should produce the output, i.e, value you want:
  eks_managed_node_groups = merge([
    for cluster in var.clusters : {
      for worker in cluster.eks_workers :
      worker.name => {
        instance_type = worker.instance_type
      }
    }
  ]...) # do not remove the ..., it's a special operator

The thing that can be a bit confusing is that the clusters variable is a list, and then you also have the eks_workers key, which points to a list of maps. Because of this, you need to access the inner list(map), which means you need to have the two for loops in this case. Using merge built-in function and the ellipsis operator (...) helps creating the structure you want to have. Testing with local variables yields the following result:
> local.node_groups
{
  "nodes1" = {
    "instance_type" = [
      "t3.micro",
    ]
  }
  "nodes2" = {
    "instance_type" = [
      "t3.micro",
    ]
  }
}


thanks for trying, i', getting │ Error: Error in function call │  │   on main.tf line 88, in module "eks": │   88:   eks_managed_node_groups = merge([ │   89:     for cluster in var.clusters : { │   90:       for worker in cluster.eks_workers : │   91:       worker.name => { │   92:         instance_type = worker.instance_type │   93:       } │   94:     } │   95:   ]) │     ├──────────────── │     │ while calling merge(maps...) │     │ var.clusters is list of object with 1 element │  │ Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".

i just added a more real variable to the question, maybe the that will help? Thanks again!

I really don't understand what is the reason for the error. Have you copied it over as it was written in the answer? Would you mind adding it to the original post so I can see what you have tried? I just tested it again, and there are no errors.

Ah, ok, you are missing the ellipsis operator at the end. The ... is not an error.

Thanks!! i've been struggling with this for hour and although i've seen the ... operator, since i've never used it, i assumed it was like people saying "insert more stuff here". Thanks a lot!!

Please consider accepting the answer if you find it helpful.
